# Complete Feed Item using facebook real time updates

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I am  receiving response on my callbacl url as below is the response :-

"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"*******","id":"*******","time":1331687890,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}

Is there any way to get the total post or even the post id which was inserted, updated or deleted through real time api ?

Comment: but what is in the `id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to preserve the OAuth Token in your server and fetch the data yourself. The timestamp field can be used here to narrow down to the feed post.